# Dynamic axis indexing of Numpy ndarray

Tags: numpy, indexing

I want to obtain the 2D slice in a given direction of a 3D array where the `direction` (or the axis from where the slice is going to be extracted) is given by another variable.

Assuming `idx` the index of the 2D slice in a 3D array, and `direction` the axis in which obtain that 2D slice, the initial approach would be:

```
if direction == 0:
    return A[idx, :, :]
elif direction == 1:
    return A[:, idx, :]
else:
    return A[:, :, idx]
```

I'm pretty sure there must be a way of doing this without doing conditionals, or at least, not in raw python. Does numpy have a shortcut for this?

The better solution I've found so far (for doing it dynamically), relies in the transpose operator:

```
# for 3 dimensions [0,1,2] and direction == 1 --> [1, 0, 2]
tr = [direction] + range(A.ndim)
del tr[direction+1]

return np.transpose(A, tr)[idx]
```

But I wonder if there is any better/easier/faster function for this, since for 3D the transpose code almost looks more awful than the 3 if/elif. It generalizes better for ND and the larger the N the more beautiful the code gets in comparison, but for 3D is quite the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transpose is cheap (timewise).  There are `numpy` functions that use it to move the operational axis (or axes) to a known location - usually the front or end of the shape list.  `tensordot` is one that comes to mind.

Other functions construct an indexing tuple.  They may start with a list or array for ease of manipulation, and then turn it into a tuple for application.  For example

```
I = [slice(None)]*A.ndim
I[axis] = idx
A[tuple(I)]
```

`np.apply_along_axis` does something like that.  It's instructive to look at the code for functions like this.

I imagine the writers of the `numpy` functions worried most about whether it works robustly, secondly about speed, and lastly whether it looks pretty.  You can bury all kinds of ugly code in a function!.

---

`tensordot` ends with

```
at = a.transpose(newaxes_a).reshape(newshape_a)
bt = b.transpose(newaxes_b).reshape(newshape_b)
res = dot(at, bt)
return res.reshape(olda + oldb)
```

where the previous code calculated `newaxes_..` and `newshape...`.

`apply_along_axis` constructs a `(0...,:,0...)` index tuple

```
i = zeros(nd, 'O')
i[axis] = slice(None, None)
i.put(indlist, ind)
....arr[tuple(i.tolist())]
```

Comment: Very interesting post thanks! If I'm not wrong, transpose just returns an array with the `strides` changed, right? It doesn't reorder the data in memory unless you call `.copy()`. According to a couple of `%timeit` tests, with `A = np.random.randn(1000,1000)`, and `B = A.T`, accessing to a random column in `A[:, idx]` is slower than accessing the same data in `B[idx]`. However, if we fully index `B[idx, :]`, accessing the data in `B` becomes more expensive. Is a matter of some `50 ns` (x1.25 speedup), so not important rly, but I'm curious. Do you know how this works in numpy?

Comment: These are all views.  It's not iterating over the data or coping it.  So the time differences have to do with parsing the expression and creating a new array object (same data pointer).  `flags` and `__array_interface__` look the same whether I use `B[100]` or `A.T[100,:]`.

Answer (score -1):

To index a dimension dynamically, you can use [swapaxes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html), as shown below:

```
a = np.arange(7 * 8 * 9).reshape((7, 8, 9))

axis = 1
idx = 2

np.swapaxes(a, 0, axis)[idx]
```

#### Runtime comparison

Natural method (non dynamic) :

```
%timeit a[:, idx, :]
300 ns ± 1.58 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

swapaxes:

```
%timeit np.swapaxes(a, 0, axis)[idx]
752 ns ± 4.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Index with list comprehension:

```
%timeit a[[idx if i==axis else slice(None) for i in range(a.ndim)]]
```

Comment: `swapaxes` wouldn't return spatially consistent results. e.g. for a `[100, 200, 300]` array, if I was to index the last axis (e.g. `data[:, :, 5]`), I would expect a `[100, 200]` array back. However, if we perform `data.swapaxes(0, 2)[5]` what we get instead is a `[200, 100]` array, because the axis `0` is now at the end. It works fine for `[0, 1]` axis', but only for those.

Comment: That's true, I overlooked that. The same data are selected but the order may change.

Answer (score -1):

This is python. You could simply use `eval()` like this:

```
def get_by_axis(a, idx, axis):
    indexing_list = a.ndim*[':']
    indexing_list[axis] = str(idx) 
    expression = f"a[{', '.join(indexing_list)}]"
    return eval(expression)
```

**Obviously**, in which case you do not accept input from *untrusted* users.