# numpy index on a variable axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I want to index over a multi dimensional array like this:

```
a = range(12).reshape(3, 2, 2)
def fun(axis, state):
    # if axis=0
    return a[state, :, :]
    # if axis=1 it should return a[:, state, :]
```

Sample outputs:

```
fun(0, 1)
array([[4, 5],                                 
       [6, 7]]) 

fun(1, 1)
array([[2, 3],
       [6, 7],
       [10, 11]])
```

In short I want to accept the axis as an argument.

I can't think of a way to do this. Any possible solutions?

Comment: See also `dynamic axis indexing`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094641/dynamic-axis-indexing-of-numpy-ndarray/31094758#31094758; Some `numpy` functions use `transpose` (`rollaxis`), others construct an indexing tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a view of the array with a specified axis moved to the front using [`numpy.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html#numpy.rollaxis):

```
def fun(a, axis, state):
    return numpy.rollaxis(a, axis)[state]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(12).reshape([3, 2, 2])
>>> def fun(a, axis, state):
...     return numpy.rollaxis(a, axis)[state]
...
>>> fun(a, 0, 1)
array([[4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
>>> fun(a, 1, 1)
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
```

`numpy.rollaxis` also supports moving axes to other positions, though the way it interprets the arguments for that is kind of weird.