# combine/replace arrays of selected indices/rows along a specific axis of a N-D array with their sum

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have N-D numpy array, e.g.:

```
a = np.arange(21).reshape(7,3)

[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]
 [15 16 17]
 [18 19 20]]
```

and an array of index arrays along specific axis, e.g.:

```
rows = np.array([np.array([1,2]), np.array([0,4,6])])
```

What I want to achieve is for each array in `rows`(e.g. [1,2]), I want to sum the rows of `a` along a specific axis (e.g. `axis=0`) and put it in place of the first index in that selection of `row`s (e.g. `1`) and delete the rest of the rows in that selection (e.g. `2`). The final output for the above example will look like:

```
[[30 33 36]  <- sum of rows(0,4,6)
 [ 9 11 13]  <- sum of rows(1,2)
 [ 9 10 11]  <- row (3)
 [15 16 17]] <- row (5)
```

I have this solution for it:

```
for i in rows:
    a[i[0]] = a[i].sum(axis=0)
a = np.delete(a, np.hstack([i[1:] for i in rows]), axis=0)
```

And I know I can do it with `ravel` and `pandas`, but I feel like there should be a more elegant way of doing it. Also, the solution has to work for any N-D array and a selected axis. Thank you.

Comment: That's a pretty unusual action, so I doubt if there's any thing 'elegant' (i.e. coded by someone else as part of the standard `numpy`).  Though instead of using `delete` you might just want to build a new array from `a` and the `rest`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. maybe a simpler question would be is there a way to combine/sum two rows of an array into one? Also, is there a reason why delete would work slower than building a new array (assuming memory is not limited)?

Comment: `np.delete` makes a new array.  Nothing wrong with it, except being general purpose, it tends to be a bit slower than a more direct action.  But it may be simplest thing to use in this case (I haven't paid close attention to how you are building the final array, after doing the sums).

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there is no better answer, here is the solution mentioned in the question for a dynamic axis inspired by @hpaulj's [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094758/4975981):

```
axs=0
for i in rows:
  I = [slice(None)]*a.ndim
  I_0 = [slice(None)]*a.ndim
  I[axs] = i
  I_0[axs] = i[0]
  a[tuple(I_0)] = a[tuple(I)].sum(axis=axs)
a = np.delete(a, np.hstack([i[1:] for i in rows]), axis=axs)
```

and adding per @hpaulj's comment to index rest instead of deleting (while above code dynamically selects axis, this is not selecting axis dynamically, but it is easy to convert to dynamic style):

```
axs=0
for i in rows:
    a[i[0]] = a[i].sum(axis=axs)
a = a[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(a.shape[axs]), np.hstack([i[1:] for i in rows])), :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and **getitem** to select only certain rows.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(21).reshape(7,3)
rows = np.array([0, 4, 6]) 

# here is the code:
# only select rows that are in the array called "rows" 
b = list(map(a.__getitem__, rows)) 
a = np.sum(b, axis = 0)    #np.sum works fine on a list
```

OK, now you do this across multiple index lists.

```
rows = np.array([np.array([1,2]), np.array([0,4,6])]) 

# here is the code:
b=[ np.sum(list(map(a.__getitem__, el)),axis =0) for el in rows] 
print(np.array(b))
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. The question is a bit different though. It requires replacing it and  removing extra rows. Also, it needs to be generalizable to any dynamic axis of a N-D array. I think this code is equivalent to the line inside for loop in question. Thank you.