# Roll first column by 1, second column by 2, etc

Tags: python, numpy, cupy

I have an array in numpy. I want to roll the first column by 1, second column by 2, etc.

Here is an example.

```
>>> x = np.reshape(np.arange(15), (5, 3))
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

What I want to do:

```
>>> y = roll(x)
>>> y
array([[12, 10,  8],
       [ 0, 13, 11],
       [ 3,  1, 14],
       [ 6,  4,  2],
       [ 9,  7,  5]])
```

What is the best way to do it?

The real array will be very big. I'm using cupy, the GPU version of numpy. I will prefer solution fastest on GPU, but of course, any idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use advanced indexing:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.reshape(np.arange(15), (5, 3))

h, w = x.shape

rows, cols = np.arange(h), np.arange(w)
offsets = cols + 1
shifted = np.subtract.outer(rows, offsets) % h

y = x[shifted, cols]
```

y:

```
array([[12, 10,  8],
       [ 0, 13, 11],
       [ 3,  1, 14],
       [ 6,  4,  2],
       [ 9,  7,  5]])
```

Comment: It breaks if `w > h`

Comment: Great catch, thank you! I've edited my solution to add a `% h` to bring all of the shifted values back between 0..h

Comment: `subtract.outer` doesn't exist in cupy, so I changed the line to `shifted = (rows[:, cp.newaxis] - offsets) % h`. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a naive solution (`roll_for`) and compares it to @Chrysophylaxs 's solution (`roll_indexing`).

Conclusion: `roll_indexing` is faster for small arrays, but the difference shrinks when the array goes bigger, and is eventually slower than `roll_for` for very large arrays.

Implementations:

```py
import numpy as np

def roll_for(x, shifts=None, axis=-1):
    if shifts is None:
        shifts = np.arange(1, x.shape[axis] + 1)  # OP requirement
    xt = x.swapaxes(axis, 0)  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094758/13636407
    yt = np.empty_like(xt)
    for idx, shift in enumerate(shifts):
        yt[idx] = np.roll(xt[idx], shift=shift)
    return yt.swapaxes(0, axis)


def roll_indexing(x):
    h, w = x.shape
    rows, cols = np.arange(h), np.arange(w)
    offsets = cols + 1
    shifted = np.subtract.outer(rows, offsets) % h  # fix
    return x[shifted, cols]
```

Tests:

```py
M, N = 5, 3
x = np.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N)
expected = np.array([[12, 10, 8], [0, 13, 11], [3, 1, 14], [6, 4, 2], [9, 7, 5]])

assert np.array_equal(expected, roll_for(x))
assert np.array_equal(expected, roll_indexing(x))

M, N = 100, 200
# roll_indexing did'nt work when M < N before fix
x = np.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N)
assert np.array_equal(roll_for(x), roll_indexing(x))
```

Benchmark:

```py
M, N = 100, 100
x = np.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N)
assert np.array_equal(roll_for(x), roll_indexing(x))
%timeit roll_for(x)       # 859 µs ± 2.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%timeit roll_indexing(x)  # 81 µs ± 255 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)



M, N = 1_000, 1_000
x = np.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N)
assert np.array_equal(roll_for(x), roll_indexing(x))
%timeit roll_for(x)       # 12.7 ms ± 56.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit roll_indexing(x)  # 12.4 ms ± 13.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)



M, N = 10_000, 10_000
x = np.arange(M * N).reshape(M, N)
assert np.array_equal(roll_for(x), roll_indexing(x))
%timeit roll_for(x)       # 1.3 s ± 6.46 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit roll_indexing(x)  # 1.61 s ± 4.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm running it on GPU, indexing should always be faster due to loops don't benefit from parallel computing. Tested with M=100000, N=1000, roll_for took 1.8 second, roll_indexing took 0.002 second. So I'll choose @Chrysophylaxs's answer.